PostGIS data with serial id doesn't automatically calc a proper id when adding new geometry
I have a postgis-geo-dataset  where I implemented various version of autoincremented ids.

The  most common one with id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Another one using a sequence with CREATE SEQUENCE xy_data.id_seq and referring to that sequence in the CREATE statement with id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('schaden_data.schaden_id_seq'), and
A third one by using a trigger function NEW.id := nextval('schaden_data.schaden_id_seq'); combined with BEFORE INSERT ON schaden_data.schaden in the trigger statement

Adding test-records (e.g. using dbeaver) in PostGIS  works fine and autoincremented ids are calculated without any troubles.
On the QGIS side things are quite different: adding a geometry by using the "toggle editing" & "add xy feature" commands, shows a default id value 0 for the very first dataset. adding another geometry again displays a default 0 value within a highlighted id-fiel. where the highlighting obviously is a "uniqe values warning" for that id field. but the id-value is not automatically incrementet to the next value - that would be 1.
Manually changing the id value to 1 changes the status of the id-field too - so the uniqueness-check of the id works fine but not the autoincrement functionality.
are any workarounds to handle auto-ids of PostGIS data within the QGIS "frontend"-forms ?
PS - additional detail: using triggers for created_by / updated_by (user) and created_at / updated_at (timestamps) works perfectly !

GDAL seems to create tables this way: ogc_fid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"my_table_ogc_fid_seq"'::regclass).  This is from "public" schema.

found a way: thanks to Auto-increment id when adding a feature to a PostGIS layer in QGIS where using the data type BIGSERIAL is suggested in this way: ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN idcolumn BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
but at first even this way did not work. after implementing the changes in PostgreSQL i had to restart QGIS, remove the layer which was related to the PostGIS table and add the it again into the QGIS project.
it seems that the information about an existing layer is not updated on reopening the project ...
